# How to generate table elements with loops in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

So I was given a piece of code to go thorough and optimise and this bits actually got me a bit stuck, the original programmer appended everything to the thead one at a time but I thought doing an array with the content and appending it within the array would be a better idea.

```
// loop through length of list and create a th while appending a message into it..
            var tt = ['ID', 'Name', 'Price', 'Quantity', 'Item Total'];
            for(i; i < tt.length; i++){
                header.appendChild(document.createElement('th').appendChild(document.createTextNode(tt[i])));
                console.log('pushed')
            }
```

However this doesn't seem to be working in fact chrome is skipping straight over the inside of the for loop. I is declared as a global as I want to use a few loops within this program. Anyone got any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The element you end up appending is the text node itself, because the return value of `document.createElement('th').appendChild(document.createTextNode(tt[i]))` is the textnode. You'll have to split it up:

```
        var tt = ['ID', 'Name', 'Price', 'Quantity', 'Item Total'];
        for(i; i < tt.length; i++) {
            var th = document.createElement('th');
            th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(tt[i]));
            header.appendChild(th);
            console.log('pushed')
        }
```

Comment: Figured it out about two seconds later! Felt a bit slow to say the least with it! Updated code is posted below :)

Answer (score 0):

And now I feel a bit slow about 5 minutes later I figured out that if I assign the TH value to a variable that it will attach to the dom so the updated code is...

```
var tt = ['ID', 'Name', 'Price', 'Quantity', 'Item Total'];
            for(i; i < tt.length; i++){
                var x = document.createElement('th');
                x.appendChild(document.createTextNode(tt[i]))
                header.appendChild(x);
            }
```